# Xamarin Forms raising NotImplementedException on creating NetHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I have client server app which uses WCF for connection. Now I'm working on Xamarin.Forms app and want to connect to WCF service (profile 7). But when I'm  trying to create 
`var binding = new NetHttpBinding();`
 binding it raising NotImplementedException. What may cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono implementation of WCF was behind .net WCF implementation for a long time. And probably still is. This is the reason for "NotImplementedException" exceptions.

If BasicHttpBinding can make you happy then you are lucky. For anything more complex, you'll need to wait or contribute. (sorry).

Here is really basic sample:

https://github.com/shturm/mono-wcf-example

Xamarin's primary focus right now is mobile (Android and iOS), which does not mean that there is no effort to complete WCF implementation, but it is not high on the priority list.

Here is the sample how to use WCF service and mobile platforms Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS (no Xamarin.Forms, but this should not be the problem). You'll need Silverlight 5 SDK to create proxies!

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

For more details I would suggest to read following docs (and those might not reflect current status):

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/

Deeper info on WSHttpBinding can be found here:

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/wcf_wshttpbindinghacking/